# how to Install air application on android tablet?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex3, android

How can i install air desktop application on android tablet? I am trying to install application by badge installer. It is not doing nothing after clicking on badge "Install Now" button click.

Android Tablet android version: 4.0.3
Air version: 3.2
Flex SDK: 3.6

So is there any other way to install air application? Please guide, any web link or sample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a mobile flex project in order to install a Flex application on android...

The mobile project has skin/components optimized for mobile devices, but you can still use the normal ones, adding the swc you need...

Once you create a mobile project you can choose which target do you want for your application:

Android / iOS / BlackBerry then when you export the release build you can:

- Export directly in the mobile format (.apk for android), with automatically install it on any devices plugged into the computer
- Export the project in a desktop installer (.air)

Look into the application.xml for more installing options...